# How to get Business Days and exclude US Holidays with Python

Tags: python, robotframework

I am a beginner in Python and wonder if some might help with give code that's not doing what I expect. The goal is to get only business days (M,T,W,T,F) and exclude US federal holidays that relate to corporate world.

The argument I pass input over the Robot Framework based in Python is:

```
Date By Adding Business Days    2021-05-13 18:38    14
```

To explain the input means. Call the method, pass current system date, and pass 14 days.

The Python code is:

```
import datetime
def add_business_days(current_date, business_days_to_add):
    num_whole_weeks  = business_days_to_add / 5
    extra_days       = num_whole_weeks * 2

    first_weekday    = current_date.weekday()
    remainder_days   = business_days_to_add % 5

    natural_day      = first_weekday + remainder_days
    if int(natural_day) > 4:
        if first_weekday == 5:
            extra_days += 1
        elif first_weekday != 6:
            extra_days += 2

    return current_date + timedelta(business_days_to_add + extra_days)
```

The output I get is:

```
**TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'int'**
```

The expectation I have is the code logic returning 14 Business Days from current date which for give date must be: **2021-06-03 18:38**

Please help...

Comment: Looks, like the value `natural_date` is of type string. Therefore comparing `natural_date > 4` is not valid and it raises above erorr.

Comment: Please include the _full_ stack trace! This tells you _which line_ threw the error. You don't go to a doctor and say "It hurts", do you?

Comment: You need to do `if int(natural_day) > 4` to cast `natural_day` to an integer.

Comment: Are you sure this error is caused by this code?  (Please include the full traceback by the way). I don't think the `natural_day` variable should be a string. If it is, use the `int` class to convert it to an integer.

Comment: Hello- I entered line integer as recommended by @CharlesDupont and PYer but get another error:  TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'int'

Comment: `natural_day` _can't_ be a string because it comes from `current_date.weekday()` (an integer) and `business_days_to_add % 5`, which is also an integer. Please include the **full stack trace** and a [mre] that people can copy into their environments to reproduce your error, because without it any answers you get will probably be guesswork. Your code works perfectly fine for me: `add_business_days(datetime.datetime.now(), 3)` gives me May 19 (which is _four_ business days, but that's another problem)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your robot parameters that you are passing to add_business_days() are strings and after that you are not parsing them to datetime and integer. So this is my modification to your code:

```
import datetime
def add_business_days(current_date_str, business_days_to_add_str):
    current_date =  datetime.datetime.strptime(current_date_str, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')
    business_days_to_add = int(business_days_to_add_str)
    num_whole_weeks  = business_days_to_add / 5
    extra_days       = num_whole_weeks * 2

    first_weekday    = current_date.weekday()
    remainder_days   = business_days_to_add % 5

    natural_day      = first_weekday + remainder_days
    if int(natural_day) > 4:
        if first_weekday == 5:
            extra_days += 1
        elif first_weekday != 6:
            extra_days += 2

    return current_date + datetime.timedelta(business_days_to_add + extra_days)
```

and simple robot test:

```
*** Test Cases ***
temp test1
    ${output}    add_business_days    2021-05-13 18:38    14
```

this prints in the console:

```
TRACE : Arguments: [ '2021-05-13 18:38' | '14' ]
TRACE : Return: datetime.datetime(2021, 6, 2, 18, 38)
INFO : ${output} = 2021-06-02 18:38:00
```

If don't parse the datetime and the string you got error on the first line trying division because you are trying to divide string by a number:

```
 TRACE : Arguments: [ '2021-05-13 18:38' | '14' ]
 TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'unicode' and 'int'
 businesDays.py", line 3, in add_business_days
    num_whole_weeks  = business_days_to_add / 5
```

PS: run you test with this command line switch:

> -L trace

in this way you will see on what exact line your code is failing

Comment: I appreciate your valuable guidance, but there is two problems in above code. When running on Robot Framework with arguments: [ '2021-05-14 11:17 | '14' ], I got output: '2021-06-05 01:41:00' but Saturday shouldn't have counted. Also the time changed. Your advise is high appreciated.

Comment: @R N, if you think that the answer was useful, then you can vote up for it.

Comment: I do appreciate your answer but didn't meet my expectations considering the question seek excluding Holidays and Weekends, but above solution not handling Holidays plus time differ, that led to Saturday ET inclusion. Take Care.